# App in wordpress doesnt fit to mobile screen

Tags: mobile

I have a Wordpress Site where I have added a small html,CSS,Js "BraSizeCalculator" app.

When I host this app in a free hosting site (https://brasizecalculator.000webhostapp.com/)
it looks fine in mobile screen.
Meaning the whole app displays on the mobile screen looks most likely a miniature of the original app.

But once I add it to Wordpress page, only half of the app displays on mobile screen 
& doesn't allow scrolling horizontally.
(http://sklep.opulenzaactive.com/jak-sie-mierzyc/)

So I have modified the CSS elements to take sizes in percentage (eg: width: 23%).
in below wordpress site.
(http://sklep.opulenzaactive.com/deelliiee/)

It is under construction yet, but I need to know is 
it possible to get the look in (https://brasizecalculator.000webhostapp.com/) 
as this site..or ..do I have to keep to above (sklep.opulenzaactive.com/deelliiee/)?

Comment: Even your first example doesn't show up completely on mobile for me. You can debug this with the small screen simulator in Chrome's inspector: a small icon in the upper left that switches the page size. I'm not sure whether this is really a WordPress problem or something else. And maybe it's easier to write that calculator on your own? It's a dead simple formula that requires very little JavaScript, and you'd get exactly what you need, not one bit more. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be as toscho said in the comments - to write your own script an make it mobile friendly from the start. But if you want a quick, temporary solution you could do something like this:

```
<div id="maincontainerWrapper" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div id="maincontainer" style="position: relative;">
          ...
    </div>
</div>
```

then your calculator app will be accessible in full width by dragging it left and right which would be uncomfortable and unintuitive for your users.